# how can I modify my sed command to only substitute and not append when the pattern is not found

Tags: sed

I have a file with two lines

```
A[0x000]:   0x00120001  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
A[0x000]:   0x12341234  0x11110987  0x34567890  0x45789756
```

and a sed command

```
sed -E -i  's|(A\[0x000\]:\s+0x)[0-9]+|\1xx0000x|g' filename
```

This command substitutes on first line and appends on second line how can i prevent the appending on second line. i would want to modify this command.

My sed command currently works this way:

```
A[0x000]:   0x00xx000x  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
A[0x000]:   0x00xx000x12341234  0x11110987  0x34567890  0x45789756
```

but I want the below result:

```
A[0x000]:   0x00xx000x  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
A[0x000]:   0x12341234  0x11110987  0x34567890  0x45789756
```

Comment: [edit] your question to state what it is you're trying to do. We can't tell for sure what you want to do by reading a script that doesn't do whatever that is.

Comment: The output you claim you  are getting is not consistent with what the code actually does, on any platform I tried. Please [edit] to provide a proper [mre] and probably mention which OS you are on in order to figure out what nonstandard extensions (like `\s`) are supported. Ideone demo: https://ideone.com/45r4J0

Answer (score 2):

It is not very clear from question but may be this `sed` would work for you:

```bash
sed -E -e '/A\[0x000]/!b' -e :a -e 's/(0{2,}x*)[1-9]/\1x/g;ta' file

A[0x000]:   0x00xx000x  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
A[0x000]:   0x12341234  0x11110987  0x34567890  0x45789756
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `/A\[0x000]/!b`: Skip a line if line doesn't contain `A[0x000]`
- `:a`: Set label `a`
- `(0{2,}x*)`: Match 2 or more zeroes followed by 0 or more `x` and capture it in group #1
- `[1-9]`: Match digit `1-9`
- `ta`: If substitution is successful then move back to label `a`
- `\1x`: In substitution put back back-reference of group #1 followed by `x`

Comment: this command works for me but i need a slight modification to have the final result as A[0x000]:   0x00xx000x  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
A[0x000]:   0x12341234  0x11110987  0x34567890  0x45789756

Comment: could we add a filter in the sed command to check for lines containing A[0x000] because i have many lines which contain the pattern 0x

Comment: @vidya: I suggest you to please add 2 lines of requirements in your question to avoid it getting closed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to change every non-zero after `0x0+` pattern to an `x`, you can try the following `sed`

```
$ sed -E  ':a;s/(0x0+[^ \t]*)[1-9]/\1x/;ta' input_file
A[0x000]:   0x00xx000x  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
A[0x000]:   0x12341234  0x11110987  0x34567890  0x45789756
```

NOTE: This will also match on the second line if the pattern is found. To restrict to only the first line, you may want to explicitly target it with `sed -E  ':a;1s/(0x0+[^ \t]*)[1-9]/\1x/;ta' input_file`

Comment: this command works but adds character 'a' to other lines in the file. could you help me prevent it

Comment: @vidya What OS are you on? Can you provide the output you are seeing for the sample provided?

Comment: My file contains many lines with string 0x its append 'a' on them as well. i dont want that also i want the sed command to locate the string A[0x000]